# missing ether after uninstalling metamask

Tags: ether, metamask, private-key, private

Lost my ether from Metamask when I uninstalled it and it did not show up when reinstalled...but it is showing on Etherdelta with the `no private key` error in red. How do I recover it please? I'm leery of fooling around with private keys. Many thanks.

Comment: if you have taken the seed phrase, you can use it to restore your account.

Comment: thanks ...i forgot about this Q and managed to figure it out...much wiser now about these things...a few months later.

Answer (score 1):

To restore your old MetaMask accounts, you need to have backed up your 12-word seed phrase.

When setting up MetaMask for the first time, it has a button for "Restore from seed phrase", but if you missed that part, you can still do it by these steps:

- Select "Lock" in the top right menu.
- Click "Restore from seed phrase"
- Enter your 12-word seed phrase and a new password.
- Click restore.
- You will only have one account restored at first, click "Add account" (top right account menu) for any missing accounts.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. I did do the restore step a couple of times with the seed words to no effect. However I didnt use the 'lock' step and i cannot see an option in the menus for that.

Comment: Do i need to uninstall and re install for that step?

Comment: It might say "Log out" instead of "Lock", the wording is changing right now. You do not need to reinstall MetaMask to do this.

Comment: omg...it worked!! Many thanks...didn't know to keep clicking new accounts and had forgotten that id created five ot them and my eth was in #4...awesome. Glad it was was a test amount i was playing with! Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks again DanF. I dont understand these sites or how to use them or   how to vote etc...so not sure if there is anything further for me to do...just thanks muchly.